# Vscode debug error for Deno application: Could not connect to debug target at

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging, deno

I am following deno course on Pluralsight (Deno: Getting Started). I am on debugging module. When I try to start the debugger, I am getting this error message on vscode:

[image: Error processing launch: Error: Could not connect to debug target]

This is my launch settings:

```
{
        "name": "Launch Deno",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "pwa-node",
        "program": "affiliate_data_server.ts",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "runtimeExecutable": "deno",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "run",
            "--inspect",
            "--allow-all"
        ],
        "attachSimplePort": 8888
    },
```

Debug console gives only this output:

`C:\Users\kara\.deno\bin\deno.exe run --inspect --allow-all affiliate_data_server.ts`

Sometimes, when I click to cancel, application still listens on the port, so i have to kill the process manually.

When i try this config instead;

```
{
        "name": "Node Deno",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "runtimeExecutable": "deno",
        "runtimeArgs": ["run", "--inspect", "-A", "affiliate_data_server.ts"],
        "port": 9229
    },
```

It starts the server but breakpoints are not working.

What would be the solution?

Comment: There's a discussion around this at https://github.com/denoland/vscode_deno/issues/384

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue by downgrading the Deno to version 1.6.1 with

```
deno upgrade --version 1.6.1
```

Source: [Github](https://github.com/denoland/vscode_deno/issues/12#issuecomment-750479813)

Comment: Since you have a workaround, please [mark your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/):)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--inspect-brk` instead of `--inspect` so it will break on the first line of the program.